# Socket.io - Server listen to specific room

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

as mentioned in Socket.io Doc about [rooms](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/) - i know that the server can move sockets to a specific room and send an event to that specific room

**transfer socket to a room :**

```
io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
  socket.join('roomId');
});
```

**emit event to sockets in that room :**

```
io.to('roomId').emit('some event');
```

but i can't find **a way that the server will listen to event coming only from a specific room**, something like:

```
io.in('roomId').on('someevent',(socket)=>{....})
```

Answer (score 3):

Socket.io has no function for this. You will have to listen for everyone on that event and check the socket's joined rooms array.